# Java Concurrent Hashmap memory usage

Tags: java, concurrenthashmap

I have 642million records to be uploaded into java concurrent hashmap. The size of the entire data set on disk is only 30GB. However, when I am uploading it to memory, almost 250GB of memory is consumed. 
I don't have any explanation for such a overhead. Can any one explain it? Also, suggest any idea how to reduce the memory consumption..

Comment: How does each record look like? How many individual records are there? What are your access pattering requirements? Why are you loading such huge datasets into memory?

Comment: The way you load and process it may have an impact on how much memory ends up flying about - can you show us the code?

Comment: Are you loading Strings? Did you read up on the memory consumption of Strings on the JVM?

Comment: I would recommend using another in memory database rather than a `ConcurrentHashMap`.

Comment: Your data is huge so just this much details won't help you. Share your code

Comment: I don't think loading that much data into memory is sensible. You should index it on the filesystem and access it from there - possibly with caching.  This would be exactly what a noSQL key->value store will do for you. Use, for example, Redis or CouchDB, to hold your data.

Comment: Mind sharing some details about the hardware you get to use for this attempt?

Comment: You're server has more than 250GB of RAM?

Comment: Please add more information.

Comment: That's not terribly surprising?  Loading things onto the heap _will_ usually consume more memory than they did on the filesystem -- filesystem formats will usually be optimized for memory consumption -- and CHM takes a significant memory overhead itself.  None of this is particularly avoidable.

Comment: @IsaiahvanderElst why the surprise? Modern servers often have 256GB or more of RAM. Many larger servers take 1-2TB of RAM. This is a _server_ not a PC.

Comment: @BoristheSpider I'm lucky if the application server is allocated 4GB.